# No me deja establecer a un array double la longitud a través de Scanner

Tags: java, array, scanner

Estoy intentando hacer que se guarde la longitud de un arreglo de números reales (por eso definido con la variable primitiva `double []`) a través de la clase `Scanner` pero por mucho que intento me salta el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
> Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int

Código:

```
double arraySolicitarR [];

        do {
        
        
        System.out.println("Introduce la longitud del array de los Reales");
        
        arraySolicitarR = new double[teclas.nextDouble()];
        
        
    }while(arraySolicitarR.length == 0);
```

Comment: una dimensión o tamaño es un entero ,no puedes decir un array de 2.1 .... new double[teclas.nextInt()];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta línea te debería mostrar un error que indica tipos incompatibles,

```
arraySolicitarR = new double[teclas.nextDouble()];
```

ya que **solo puedes definir valores enteros como dimensión de un array**, por lo tanto en lugar de obtener un valor double, usa valores enteros mediante el uso de `nextInt()`:

```
    //arraySolicitarR = new double[teclas.nextDouble()];
    arraySolicitarR = new double[teclas.nextInt()];
```